# Get user id by passed token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to open a url of server-generated file in a new tab so user can download it, this link should not be accessible for public users, only authenticated user should access this file.
I was thinking to pass the token in the url as a query paramter to be something like http://website.com/generate-file?token=passed-token.

my question is, is asp identity has any api I can use to get user id or user object by access token?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for:

```
UserManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync("Generate file", userId);
```

This will generate a token for that user for this specific purpose (`"Generate file"`). Later you can verify the token and verify the user with:

```
UserManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(userId, "Generate file", token);
```

However this requires you to also put userID in the query parameter, which I don't see is a big issue provided that the link can only be accessed by the user (maybe sent to the user's email?). Otherwise no there isn't a way to get an userID from a token alone.